# Laravel: follow the second relationship of a model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am trying to access the relation of a Ticket to give me a list of Devices and Rooms but I can't get it to work.

You should give me the Rooms (including the devices).

In the pivot table, it can be the room_id (when it refers to the whole room) or in Device_id (when it refers to only a specific Device), in case this one the other should be Null

Would it be better to divide it into 2 tables? one for Devices and one for Rooms? or if it is possible to do it with Relationships?

Thanks a lot! :D

```
helpdesk_rooms
  id
  name


helpdesk_devices
  id
  name
  room_id


helpdesk_tickets_rooms_devices
  ticket_id
  room_id (Null when Device ID is set)
  device_id (Null when Room ID is set)

helpdesk_tickets
  id
  name
```

```
Device HasOne Room

Ticket HasMany Devices
Ticket HasMany Rooms
```

```php
class Device extends Model
{
    
    protected $table = 'helpdesk_devices';
    //public $primaryKey = null;
  
    public function deviceRoom()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Room::class);
    }
```

```php
class Ticket extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'helpdesk_tickets';


    public function roomsDirect()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Room::class,
            TicketRoomDevice::class,
            'ticket_id', // Foreign key on the TicketRoomDevice table...
            'id', // Foreign key on the Rooms table...
            'id', // Local key on the Ticket table...
            'room_id' // Local key on the TicketRoomDevice table...
        );
    }

    // How to get the Room name from Device -> Room (Name) ??    
    public function roomsDevices()
    {
        return $this->roomsDirect()-> ???;

    }
```

Comment: I think you're looking for polymorphic relationships. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach for this type of situation, in laravel it is solved by polymorphic relations.

In the example that you raise it would be something like this:

helpdesk_rooms

- id
- name

helpdesk_devices

- id
- name
- room_id

helpdesk_tickets

- ticket_id
- tickeable_id
- tickeable_type

```php
    class Device extends Model
    {
        public function ticket()
        {
            return $this->morphOne(Ticket::class, 'tickeable');
        }
    }
    
    class Room extends Model
    {
        public function ticket()
        {
            return $this->morphOne(Ticket::class, 'tickeable');
        }
    }
    
    class Ticket extends Model
    {
        public function tickeable()
        {
            return $this->morphTo();
        }
    }
```

This will allow you to work comfortably with your additional relationships in addition to saving you more complicated tables and configurations.
You can check more in the official documentation [polymorphic-relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships)

Comment: I solved it with a polymorphic many-to-many relationship guiding me in your answer. Thank you!